# How to display image url from firebase into html table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, firebase-realtime-database

I have a problem on how to display images in html table.

Based on the code below, the Image column only display the link of the image and not the image itself. How can I display the actual image into my Image column?

[image]

```
 root.on('child_added', function(childSnapshot) {
        rootRef10 = childSnapshot.val();
        var tr = document.createElement('tr');
        tr.appendChild(createCell(imageUrl));
        tr.appendChild(createCell(videoUrl));
        table.appendChild(tr);
    });

  function createCell(text) {
        var td = document.createElement('td');
        td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(text));
        return td;
    }
```

Comment: Please provide the code for your `createCell()` method

Comment: @tvicky4j247 I already update the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this:

```
// put your image url as the url parameter
function createImageCell(url) {
    var td = document.createElement('td');
    var img = document.createElement("img");
    img.src = url;
    td.appendChild(img);
    return td;
}
```

So basically replace `tr.appendChild(createCell(imageUrl));` with `tr.appendChild(createImageCell(imageUrl));`

**EDIT:** If you want to set the width and height, you could do either:

```
function createImageCell(url) {
    var td = document.createElement('td');
    var img = document.createElement("img");
    img.src = url;
    img.width = 800; // specify width here
    img.height = 800; // specify height here
    td.appendChild(img);
    return td;
}
```

Or if you want varying widths and heights for each image, you could do:

```
function createImageCell(url, width, height) {
    var td = document.createElement('td');
    var img = document.createElement("img");
    img.src = url;
    img.width = width;
    img.height = height;
    td.appendChild(img);
    return td;
}
```

And then specify the width and height for each image whenever you call the method.

Comment: How can I set the image width and height?

Comment: Basically add `img.width = width` and `img.height = height` to the `createImageCell` function

Comment: One more question, why I cannot use the same code to display video?

Comment: Video playback requires a different tag, the `<video>` tag. The `<img>` tag only works for images.

Comment: Hi, if at certain row I dont have an image to display, how to prevent the image to be undefined?

Comment: You could display a placeholder image, or just leave the cell blank by first checking if the image url is null or empty before calling the `createImageCell` method. So do something like `if (url) { createImageCell(url); } else { // just create and return var td without any of the img stuff }`

Comment: Hi, if I want to display a specific image when url ==null, how can I do that?